# Calling Interop Word Reference in BackGroundWorker and RichTextBox Writing

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a simple application like that:

  1-) openfiledialog button to select which word document will be open.

  2-) ReadButton to Open the word Document that path is defined.

I read a func like that to open word document

```
private void ReadMSWord()
    {
        string filePath = dosyaYol.Text;

        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object path = dosyaYol.Text;
            object readOnly = false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            wordText.Text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
            Image img = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)docs).Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In this fuction example: the program gives error on the line

```
wordText.Text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

"object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Read Button Click Event

```
private void ReadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dosyaYol.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dosyaYol.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bir dosya seçmeden okuma işlemi yapamazsınız!", "Dijital Arşiv Güncelleme", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    }
```

BackGroundWorker Dowork

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadMSWord();
    }
```

And progresschanged event of BGW

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

How can i achive to report progress bar thread percentage? And show progress bar.

Comment: Both the Application and the Clipboard class are single-threaded COM objects, using them in an MTA worker thread is pretty likely to cause trouble.  Start by eliminating Clipboard, there is no point when you can use Range.  There is no meaningful way to report progress, you cannot sub-divide the operating in countable steps.  Set the ProgressBar.Style property to Marquee.

Comment: You say: There are two jobs in one thread and if i seperate them or destroy one of them even. It couldn't be enable to evaluate the progress?